# How to output a file from another non java programme into the resources folder of a java jar file

Tags: java, swing

I have an R script that outputs html and dumps it in a directory of my choosing. I also have a java Swing application with a WebView component that allows me to see the html from within the Swing application.

This works OK on most computers but because the outputted html contains a base64 image, for some reason the image cannot be viewed from the Swing WebViewer on certain operating systems(although the rest of the html can-I can see the images on my mac but not on Windows 2003).

I think this is a problem relating to the security of a java programme accessing resources outside of the programme that maybe permissions are not set up for or something.

To simplify things I want to dump the html in resources that are local to the Swing application (ie in a resources folder) that would be contained within the deployed jar. How can I do this? Is this even possible?

Comment: 1) *"Swing application with a WebView"* Note that `WebView` is a Java-FX class. 2) *"output a file .. into the resources folder of a java jar file"* A Jar file is 'read only' when it is loaded in a JRE, so it is not possible.

Comment: Im using JavaFx in swing. If I allow the user to specify a folder using the Preferences class maybe thats a way round- I will try

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this possible. This way you have to

- Script: inserts the content within the jar file (root folder within the jar)
- Swing: program has to be (re-)started
- Swing: read file from within jar (e.g. with getResourceAsStream - method of the class loader)

Comment: OK. Not keen on restarting Swing. Is there a way to do this without restarting Swing?

Comment: No, it is not. The jar is loaded when you start your program - you cannot reload your program while you're using it. You have to set the correct rights for the Java program to have access to your folder.